# Is it possible to use a return value as a parameter when calling the method again, in a different method

Tags: java

Sorry if this is a confusing question or a duplicate. So I have a boolean method called "Driveable" when that is true, I'd like to print out the speed a car is going. I then also want to show what gear the car is. However, I want to pass the int "speed" and will enter the parameter when I call that method.However, when I call this method in my "gearChange" method it is asking me to enter an integer, I dont want to enter an interger though, I want to pass the parameter I already entered in the "speed" method. So is it possible to pass a parameter or return value when calling that method again in another method? Sorry again for the confusing question. I realize there maybe other ways to get my answer but for future reference, I want to know if something like this is possible. So I'm not too concerned with the code below or making changes, more so just the possibilities of doing something like this.

```
public static int speed(int speed){

  if(driveable()){

     System.out.print(" you are going " + speed + " miles per hour");
     return speed;   
   }else{

     System.out.print("The car is not drive able");
     return -1; 

   }

}

public static void gearChange(){
  //here:
  if(speed(speed) >= 1 && speed(speed) <= 20){

      System.out.print("You are in first gear");

    etc...

}

speed(int 15);

gearChange();
```

Comment: it's unclear what you're asking and please format your code properly.

Comment: Can I ask how it's not properly formatted? Or What would make it formatted correctly? Is it the spacing? Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO.

Yes, you can set variables outside of methods.  Note: this is not very intelligible code, but I am including it to demonstrate how you can set a variable outside of a method.  I also slightly updated the naming to distinguish the variables.

```
private int currentSpeed;

public static boolean driveable() {

    return true; //or whatever your logic may be
}

public int testSpeed(int speed) {

    if (driveable()) {

        System.out.print(" you are going " + speed + " miles per hour");
        this.currentSpeed = speed;
        return speed;
    }

    else {

        System.out.print("The car is not driveable");
        this.currentSpeed = speed;
        return -1;
    }

}

public void gearChange() {

    if (testSpeed(this.currentSpeed) >= 1 && testSpeed(this.currentSpeed) <= 20) {
        System.out.print("You are in first gear");
    }

}

@Test //run in Junit to see the output
public void testIt() {

    testSpeed(15);
    gearChange();

}
```

In many cases, you would use getter and setter methods (`getX()` and `setX()` to access values (unless you're doing some functional programming).

Note that you'd also be calling the `testSpeed()` method multiple times.

You would want to revisit this design and make it clear what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks so much bphilipnyc! This is exactly what I'm looking for! I have to be sure to add in the field "this.currentSpeed" next time! I have only been coding for a month or so now. If you have time, can you explain how I get my code more intelligible? Or is this just something that comes with experience? My code and yours look very similar to me(with the exception of "this.currentSpeed") but I'm sure I am wrong haha.

Comment: Unfortunately, Allen, SO is not the right forum for that type of thing.  You can try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ to find the answers you're seeking.  That's a really helpful area too.  It can be really frustrating in the beginning.  Hang in there.

Answer (score 0):

You should have an object (for example Car) in which you set the speed and in which you have a setSpeed(int speed) method, this way when you call the method gearChange() of the same object you can retrieve the current speed (you should also check if it has been set or otherwise accept zero has correct if it has not been set).

I think you need to familiarize yourself more with OOP if you want to be comfortable in Java.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for all your help! What do you mean by "POO" is that Programming for Others? Sorry if my coding is very sloppy. Any recommendations, besides continued practice, on how to improve it?

Comment: Sorry I must've forgot that in english it's OOP (oriented object programming). In French we say POO.